# What sort of manifold is PU(H)?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces

The space underlying the projective unitary group of a separable, infinite-dimensional Hilbert space has a number of topologies, so for the purposes of this question, pick you favourite and answer for that one.

I've read that $PU(H)$ is a Fréchet manifold, but that was without saying which topology. There are two ways I can see to think about this. First is that if we know what sort of manifold $U(H)$ is, then we know what $PU(H)$ is, as the former looks locally like a chart of $PU(H)$ times $U(1)$. So we can consider the closed (I think!) subspace $U(H) \subset End(H)$.

Alternately we can consider $PU(H)$ as sitting inside the Hilbert-Schmidt operators on $H$ as the projective unitaries act freely on the latter. (EDIT: this is not right, as pointed out by Andrew. I was thinking of the inclusion $PU(H) \hookrightarrow U(HS(H))$, which doesn't really tell us much in hindsight.)

I'm not familiar enough with the analysis to turn the above observations into results, and I may be interested in other topologies.

So the question is, is there the structure of a Banach or even Hilbert manifold on $PU(H)$?

Comment: Check out http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/calgary/BG.html beginning with note 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: Theo's comments are spot-on - that'll teach me to try to post a quick answer without thinking too much*

There are two sensible topologies on $U(H)$, each leads to a topology on $P U(H)$ by quotienting:

1. The norm topology.  In this topology, $U(H)$ is viewed as a sub-Lie group of the Banach Lie group $Gl(H)$.  Here, $Gl(H)$ is open in $B(H)$ and the exponential map is a diffeomorphism onto a neighbourhood of the identity and this takes skew-Hermitian operators onto $U(H)$, thus defining charts.  As the quotient $U(H) \to P U(H)$ admits slices, this makes $P U(H)$ a Banach manifold.
2. The weak topology.  In this topology, we start with $Gl(H)$ as a subspace of $B(H)$ where this has the weak topology in which $A_\lambda \to A$ if $A_\lambda v \to A v$ for each $v \in H$.  However, this isn't good enough for $Gl(H)$ as taking the inverse isn't continuous.  So we put on it the topology so that both the inclusion $Gl(H) \to B(H)$ and the inclusion after the inversion map $A \to A^{-1}$ are continuous.  However, then $Gl(H)$ is not an open subspace of $B(H)$ so it isn't obviously a manifold.  Indeed, I don't think that with this topology then it is a manifold at all (I don't think it is an ANR).  As Theo says, the induced topology on $U(H)$ doesn't need the inversion fix, but even so it still is not a manifold.

The map to Hilbert-Schmidt operators is not useful here because the action is not free, it is only faithful.  It acts by conjugation whereupon the stabiliser group of a particular element are all the unitary elements that commute with it and this can be quite large.

Comment: I don't understand your answer: Ad 1) $U(H)$ is not open in $GL(H)$ since it doesn't contain any norm ball around the identity. How is $GL(H)$ a Banach space? It's a non-trivial open subset of $B(H)$. In order to show that $U(H)$ is a Lie group I'd try using the implicit function theorem. Ad 2) You describe the strong operator topology which happens to coincide with the weak operator topology on $U(H)$ (where this is Polish for separable $H$). Taking the adjoint is strongly cont. on normal operators, and multiplication is strongly cont. on norm-bounded sets, so this is a group topology on U(H)

Comment: To be a bit more constructive: For 1) I'd expect that the exponential map should model $U(H)$ on the skew-hermitian operators in $B(H)$. For 2) I'd expect that for separable $H$ the Stone representation theorem for strongly continuous one-parameter unitary groups via unbounded self-adjoint operators should be of use although I do not see how this would give rise to a manifold structure.

Comment: Theo, you're absolutely right.  I was thinking "$Gl(H)$" and writing quickly.  I've done a quick-fix.

Comment: The weak topology on $U(H)$ and $PU(H)$ has one very nice property: in that topology $U(H)$ and $PU(H)$ are Polish groups. As a consequence, many other topologies (strong, ultraweak, etc.) end up being equal to the weak topology. The reason is that there is a general theorem about Polish groups that says that a continuous bijective homomorphism between Polish groups is necessarily a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and correcting, Andrew. I suspected something to that effect -- this happens ot all of us :) (I leave my comments up for now because your answer refers to them. Feel free to edit the references to my comments out of your answer, and I'd remove the comments). // The point of my mentioning "Polish" in my first comment was precisely what André said. My favorite reference for this circle of ideas is Kechris's *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, GTM 156, the general theorem André mentions being (12.24) on page 81.